# Phalcon .htaccess file not working on linux server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have made a web API using the PHP phalcon framework which is running perfectly on localhost. But when I upload it to a Linux server it's not working. I think it's because of my `.htaccess` file.

Can you take look? My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have 2 htaccess files? /project/.htaccess and /project/public/.htaccess here?

Comment: What version of apache is running on the server? And localhost? And what kind of error messages are you getting? Why do you think it's a problem with `.htaccess`? What does the upload handler look like?

Comment: no sir i have only 1 file file in project/.htaccess

Comment: Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Red Hat)
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: What is your document root?

Comment: it's solved it's the htaccess problem.

Comment: Hello , how did you solve that ? I'm facing the same issue too